# Audio settings not playing well with USB headsets

Tags: sound, microphone

### Short

GUI settings not working with the USB headset. (AUDIO IN/OUT)

### Long

When setting up my headset, the headset did appear in the sound settings GUI, but when I set both the headset for Audio out and Audio in, the microphone did not work.

When I go back to the sound settings, the area where the audio in is, the option that I selected (audio in) is blank, but when I click the blank space, my microphone does show up, but it reverts the audio out back to the default (not working) audio device.

I need my headset to work because I have to keep things private between me and other people.

I looked in additional drivers and there was none for any audio device.

[image: Small screenshot of the window]